# Share a single ViewModel instance between pages in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

When I declare my MainViewModel class in App.xaml, I get this error on load:

Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 7:6. Cannot assign property "Resources": type mismatch between "MyPCL.Client.ViewModels.MainViewModel" and "Xamarin.Forms.ResourceDictionary"

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
  </Application.Resources>
```

How can I declare on global ViewModel so on every page I can do this:

```
 BindingContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a `ResourceDictionary` inside the `Application.Resources` tag:

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <viewModels:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just create a new derived `ContentPage` which sets it's `BindingContext` in the constructor like so:

```
public class MainContentPage : ContentPage {

    protected MainViewModel viewModel;

    public MainContentPage() { BindingContext = (viewModel = new MainViewModel()); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
   </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

as the error message points out. You're almost there.